# How to provide List<SqlDataSource> to XtraReport.DataSoruce?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, devexpress, xtrareport

I am using .net core application and trying to bind multiple records to XtraReport.DataSource property. For single record it is working fine but I am not sure about the multiple record.
Here is something I've done for single record using this link https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4793/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/provide-data-to-reports/bind-a-report-to-a-data-source/sql-database/bind-a-report-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-runtime-sample:

```
  private SqlDataSource BindToData() { 
        var ds = new SqlDataSource(connectionParameters);
    
        CustomSqlQuery formQuery = new CustomSqlQuery();
        formQuery.Name = "formQuery";
        formQuery.Sql = "SELECT * FROM Form where Id = 100";
        
        CustomSqlQuery formQuestionsQuery = new CustomSqlQuery();
        formQuestionsQuery.Name = "formQuestionsQuery ";
        formQuestionsQuery.Sql = "SELECT * FROM FormQuestions where FormId = 100";
    
        ds.Queries.AddRange(new SqlQuery[] {
         formQuery,
         formQuestionsQuery 
        });

        ds.Relations.Add("form", "formQuestionsQuery", "Id", "FormId");

        ds.RebuildResultSchema();
    
        return ds;
}
```

and then:

```
 XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
 report.DataSource = BindToData();
 report.DataMember = "form";
 using (var pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
   report.ExportToPdf(pdfStream); 
 }
```

Now in case of multiple records I will be receiving `List<int> formIds` in the params and in my report I want to display info of each Form on new page.

Comment: Have you tried simply designing the XtraReport with a page break for the Form ID field?

Comment: @Brendon, well actually I am totally new to this thing so no. I haven't tried that out. But can you explain me in little more detail?

Comment: Which version of the DevExpress XtraReports are you using? You can use the XRPageBreak control to insert a page break anywhere or you can set the ReportBand.PageBreak property, for instance.